# How can I convert a Node Js web application to a desktop application?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, desktop-application, localserver

I have created a Node js Web application which is running on an express server. It is a web automation application which is made using puppeteer. I want this app to run in headful mode which is not possible if I deploy this on servers (for eg Heroku). So instead of deploying this application,I wanted to create a desktop app which runs this application on the local host everytime. Is there any way to convert this web application to a desktop application and run it on local host through the desktop app only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be using Electron.

It is used for cross-platform apps with Nodejs and interacts like website, so you wouldn't need to rebuilt your app from scratch.